# unique entity in a database

Tags: database, entity, unique

How can we make a constraint on the database, so that only one entity fits in a desired position?

For example, we want to have a president for the Country database.
How can we define the "is-president" attributes so that only one entry can have the "true" value.

Comment: Ultimately it will fall on your logic, whether your DBMS complains due to a constraint issue or not.  Instead, you should check this before updating/adding your record in your code (if you are using code to do this).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I actually wanted to use it in MS Access. So, you are saying there is no specific way to do it without coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it when inserting the data to your table. If you want to add a president, first check whether there is a president or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off modelling this in a different way - for example having a `Countries` table, a `People` table, and then a `Presidents` table which has a foreign key to the `Countries` table, and a foreign key to the `People` table.

You can then add a unique constraint on the composite value of both foreign keys to ensure only 1 person exists per country within the `Presidents` table.

Comment: Thank "devdigital"! I actually wanted to know if there is any simple and light-weight solution for that. Indeed, adding a table for that case doesn't seem quite optimal to me.